# Csvhelper version 27.*.*.* doesnt support ConvertUsing for class map?? GetField is also not working

Tags: .net-core

Issue is with Convertusing. I have upgraded csvhelper with latest version and it doesnt support convertusing. And also GetField is not working.

```
 public class CashManagementRecordMap : ClassMap<CashManagementRecord>
        {
            public CashManagementRecordMap()
            {
                Map(m => m.RevenueCenterNumber).ConvertUsing(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.GetField(1)));
                
            }
    }
```